# How can I win without knowing how to play?

Tags: lateral-thinking

I have been faced with a conundrum. I have been simultaneously challenged by two of the world's best chess players to play chess. The rules are simple. I will earn two points for a win, one point for a draw, and no points if I lose. There is one fairly large problem however... I don't know how to play chess. What is a strategy that will guarantee me at least two points?

Comment: UK performer Derren Brown used this exact same trick to simultaneously challenge 9 expert chess players. Just FYI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My strategy would be to:

> Play them both at the same time.

To clarify:

> Let's call the first master player A, and the second player B. Insist that, against A, A goes first, and in the match against B, you go first. Then, let the game start:
>   - A makes their move against you.
>   - Copy that move against B.
>   - B makes their move against you.
>   - Copy that move against A.
>   - Repeat until both games are over.

At the end of the game:

> One of the players will beat you, so you get 0 points in that match. *But* your next move will finish the other match, and you'll win, getting 2 points!

Another possibility is that:

> One of the matches goes into a stalemate, getting you 1 point. The next match will also go into a stalemate on the next turn, getting you another point, for the total of 2 points!

Comment: This requires you to play first in exactly one of the games